# Are Navier-Stokes equations used in molecular biology research?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, biology

I am wondering whether Navier-Stokes equations have been used in some molecular biology research papers in the past.

A quick Google search revealed that such papers exist but I want to know if there could be some important progress related to Navier-Stokes equations, as well as in which areas of molecular biology are NS equations applied.